# Is there a way to run shake assuming some rule is up-to-date?

Tags: shake-build-system

We would like to run a Shake build while assuming some target is built, e.g. something like

```
./Build.hs --dont-rebuild my-target
```

Reading the docs it seems there should be a way to do that but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ShakeOptions` setting you are looking for is `shakeRebuild=[(RebuildLater,"my-target")]`. This setting causes Shake to not rebuild `my-target` in this run. From the documentation of [`RebuildLater`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.17.4/docs/Development-Shake.html#t:Rebuild):

> *This assumption is unsafe, and may lead to incorrect build results in this run.* Assume these files are clean in this run, but test them normally in future runs.

This setting can be applied using the command line `--skip=my-target`. A few caveats:

- `my-target` won't rebuild in this run, by things it depends on might, if they need to.
- If you next run without skipping `my-target`, it will rebuild if it needs to (the `--skip` is not sticky).

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil !